# Finish Sanding before or after wood burning in a design

Tags: sanding, pyrography

I am starting to get into pyrography and I am completing my first design; I am wondering if I should finish sand before or after I burn in the design? It would seem that after burning in the design an edge is formed that should probably be sanded down but I am afraid that sanding could rub out the design.

Comment: There's "finish sanding" and being finished sanding. The two get mixed together but they're actually distinct. You should have the surface finish-sanded before starting the pyrography, but if needed you can sand further after the burning is complete (using the same grit you used last, or even a bit finer). Then you're finished sanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would finish the sanding as much as possible prior to burning then once you have finally finished carefully hand sand with a finer grit to remove the edge.